# Pros and cons of using grocery curd library in codeigniter framework.

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I wanna integrate grocery curd library in my codeigniter framework. 
Please any one help me what are the pros and cons of this library.

Is it flexible, I am going to use multiple table joining and some bigger queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This library is very helpful if you have to make more page to insert edit delete data, because its system is very easy to use and very fast to develop.
If you have instead to make only one page for add edit delete isn't necessary grocery crud.

The other thing that you have to consider is if you have more control more particular option is a little bit difficult to do but there is a lot of way.

Other pro is that this project is follow by a forum and there are many person that answer to your question (I have used that forum and it was very helpful).

I adivse you to try this framework when you have to manage more table to add insert and delete data you can spend less time to develop.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes i go through the documentation It is really a nice one .